# Packaging python scripts within a grunt plugin

Tags: python, gruntjs

I am creating a grunt plugin that is simply [wrapping a python module](https://github.com/fatso83/grunt-codekit/tree/v0.1.3). I hope not to force the user of the plugin to pre-install the python module, and so I am packing the module with my plugin. The problem is:

**how can I find the path to the the python file when trying to execute it as a child process**?

The current working directory when executing Grunt is the top level directory of the program using the plugin, not the plugin's directory. As such, I don't know how to reference the python files in the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is mostly concerned with finding the location of the executing node module. This is found by looking up the local Node variable `__dirname` ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19174347/200987)). Once you find that location, the other essential bit is changing the PYTHONPATH to include your script location. This is the piece of code I needed

```
var cp = require('child_process')
  , path = require('path')
  , command = 'python -c \'import mypackage; mypackage.doSomething();\''
  , execOptions = {}
  , rootDirectoryOfModule =  path.join(__dirname, "..");

process.env['PYTHONPATH'] = rootDirectoryOfModule;

var childProcess = cp.exec(command, execOptions, function callback() { ... } );
```